# Functional composition of both success and error paths

Tags: scala, functional-programming

**TLDR**: I'm looking for functional programming patterns for composing both the success and failure paths of recursive, failable functions.

Scastie link for the example code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/apUioyJsSdaziPfiE14CoQ

Given a recursive datatype and failable method that operates on it:

```scala
sealed trait Expr
case class Lit(x: Int) extends Expr
case class Div(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends Expr

def evaluate(expr: Expr): Either[String, Int] = ???
```

Typical examples of functional composition show how to elegantly implement these things:

```scala
def evaluate(expr: Expr): Either[String, Int] = expr match {
  case Lit(x) => Right(x)
  case Div(l, r) =>
    for {
      x <- evaluate(l)
      y <- evaluate(r)
      res <- if (y != 0) Right(x / y) else Left("Divide by 0!")
    } yield res
}

evaluate(Div(Lit(8), Div(Lit(3), Lit(0)))) // Left("Divide by 0!")
```

This is great, except that sometimes you also want to do some kind of composition of the error messages. This is especially useful if you want parent nodes to add information to errors propagated from their children.

Perhaps I want to return an error message with context about the entire expression rather than just the information that there was a divide by 0 *somewhere*:

```scala
def evaluate2(expr: Expr): Either[String, Int] = expr match {
  case Lit(x) => Right(x)
  case Div(lhs, rhs) =>
    val l = evaluate2(lhs)
    val r = evaluate2(rhs)
    val result = for {
      x <- l
      y <- r
      res <- if (y != 0) Right(x / y) else Left(s"$x / 0")
    } yield res
    result.orElse {
      Left(s"(${l.merge}) / (${r.merge})") // take advantage of Any.toString
    }
}

evaluate2(Div(Lit(8), Div(Lit(3), Lit(0)))) // Left("(8) / (3 / 0)")
```

This isn't terrible, but it isn't great either. It's 4 lines of business logic vs. 5-6 of boiler plate.

Now, I'm not the best at functional programming, and I don't know much about Cats and Scalaz, but I do now that this smells like a reusable higher-order function. From the type that I want, I can derive a pretty useful utility function:

```scala
def flatMap2OrElse[R, A, B](x: Either[R, A], y: Either[R, A])
                           (f: (A, A) => Either[R, B])
                           (g: (Either[R, A], Either[R, A]) => R): Either[R, B] =
  (x, y) match {
    case (Right(a), Right(b)) => f(a, b)
    case _                    => Left(g(x, y))
  }
```

Then it's trivial to write a concise form:

```scala
def evaluate3(expr: Expr): Either[String, Int] = expr match {
  case Lit(x) => Right(x)
  case Div(lhs, rhs) =>
    flatMap2OrElse(evaluate3(lhs), evaluate3(rhs)) {
      (x, y) => if (y != 0) Right(x / y) else Left(s"$x / 0")
    } {
      (x, y) => s"(${x.merge}) / (${y.merge})"
    }
}

evaluate3(Div(Lit(8), Div(Lit(3), Lit(0)))) // Left("(8) / (3 / 0)")
```

The `orElse` function taking `Either`s is a bit weird, but it's my function and it can be weird if I want it to.

In any case, it seems to me that there should be a pattern here. Is the style of `evaluate2` the canonical way of doing it or are there utilities/abstractions I should be looking at to better handle this kind of thing?

**EDIT**

New Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/p0odf16PTLOTJPYSF9CGMA

This is a partial answer, but still requires a custom function that feels like it should exist somewhere. I think with just `flatMap2` we can do this pretty clearly without the boutique `flatMap2OrElse`:

```scala
def flatMap2[R, A, B](x: Either[R, A], y: Either[R, A])
                     (f: (A, A) => Either[R, B]): Either[R, B] =
  (x, y) match {
    case (Right(a), Right(b)) => f(a, b)
    case (Left(a), _)         => Left(a) // Need Either[R, B]
    case (_, Left(b))         => Left(b)
  }

def evaluate4(expr: Expr): Either[String, Int] = expr match {
  case Lit(x) => Right(x)
  case Div(lhs, rhs) =>
    val l = evaluate4(lhs)
    val r = evaluate4(rhs)
    flatMap2(l, r)((x, y) => if (y != 0) Right(x / y) else Left(s"$x / 0"))
    .orElse(Left(s"(${l.merge}) / (${r.merge})"))
}

evaluate4(Div(Lit(8), Div(Lit(3), Lit(0)))) // Left("(8) / (3 / 0)")
```

That being said, this concept should generalize beyond `flatMap2`. It just feels like this is already a thing.

Comment: ```Either``` is right biased in Scala. Furthermore in cats or else where, it is a monad. Thus it is *fixed* on one side. So composable transformations will favor the right side. Your best bet is using something like a ```fold``` which will allow you to specify a function for both ```Left``` & ```Right```  I am also a little bit confused on how exactly you want the Left side the compose. In your examples Left side is left alone. If you want to do something really complicated, It makes me wonder if ```Either``` is the correct data structure

Comment: I'm actually not leaving `Left` alone, I replace it with an aggregation of lower error messages via the `.orElse(Left(s"(${l.merge}) / (${r.merge})"))`. It's not much so easy to miss; I was just trying to keep the error message aggregation simple to keep it from being too distracting. In a real use I would probably define functions and do more complex logic. The problem is that I don't only want to process the `Left`, I need to aggregate if either side is a `Left` even if the other side is a `Right`. It's mainly about adding context at each point up the recursive structure.

Comment: Yeah I missed that. There is a lot going on here, my bad. As mentioned you can use ```fold``` for the aggregation but IMO ```Either``` is definitely not the right way to aggregate errors. A ```Semigroupal``` would be a much better fit. For example, checkout validated (https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) It allows you to accumulate error messages on the left by default

Comment: `Validated` looks more like what I'm looking for; I'll take a look. Thank you very much for your responses.